# How do I log the request duration with cloudfront?

Tags: webserver, amazon-cloudfront, access-log

How do I log the duration of a request, served with cloudfront?

With a usual apache, I would add `%D` or `%T` to the access log configuration - but this seems  not to work with cloudfront.

I used this as the reference documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CloudFront does not provide that information in the access logs.  You may want to post to this as a feature request in the [AWS CloudFront forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=46).